# UITabViewController : how to access the correct visible tab bar (selectedViewController showing wrong results)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Using the UITabBarControllerDelegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
// I want to check the currently displayed view controller and the selected one to decide what to do
if (self.selectedViewController==self.viewController1){
    if(viewController==self.viewController2 || viewController==self.viewController3){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Basically I'm checking that if a different tab is being pressed from when viewController1 is visible, do stuff. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html),

**@property(nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *selectedViewController**

Discussion

This view controller is the one whose custom view is currently displayed by the tab bar interface.

Now for the weirdness:
In my code, as you can see I reference self.selectedViewController to check the one currently displayed, and it consistently returns exactly the same as the ViewController parameter being passed but the didSelect. Maybe the self.selectedViewController has already been set to the one that will be displayed as a result of the didSelect? If so, how or where should I access it to get the one shown *before* the didSelect? I have some core data writing I need to do based on the correct path of currently shown->new tab selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tabBartController:shouldSelectViewController:` delegate method.